# How can I decrypt traffic on a WPA encrypted network?

Tags: encryption, passwords, wifi, sniffer

I am connected to a WPA/WPA2 Access Point and I want to sniff all wireless traffic inside that network. How can I decrypt the traffic even though I don't have the pre-shared key?

Comment: You mean inside of the network or outside? As you wrote you are already connected to the access point. Therefore, you do not need to decrypt the wireless packets.

Comment: The traffic has been encrypted with the key and therefore the only way to decrypt the traffic is to use the key. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

No, you need the pre-shared key.

**Longer answer**

WPA-PSK and WPA2-PSK encrypt traffic per client and session keys, which are derived from the pre-shared key.

So if you know the pre-shared key for the network (which you don't) and you sniff the four way handshake when another client joins the access point, you could decrypt only that client's traffic.

**Note**

This only applies assuming access point isolation is not enabled on the access point.

Comment: Is there a way to obtain the pre-shared key, e.g. by brute-forcing it?

Comment: how to sniff the four way handshake when another client joins the access point?

Comment: @mohammadaghazahiri airodump-ng will do the trick.